# Shape Variable Loses Reference to Some Shape Properties When the Selection is Changed

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VBA in Microsoft Word to manipulate shapes.  I have an instance where a variable loses reference to some shape properties when the selection is changed.  The following is the code.  When this code begins to run, a picture is selected in a document.  The picture is a regular shape (i.e. not an inline shape):

```
Dim MyShape As Shape
Set MyShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
MsgBox MyShape.Left
Selection.Collapse
MsgBox MyShape.Left
```

The first MsgBox command works fine, but the second one after collapsing the selection causes the following error:

> "Run-time error '4605': The Left method or property is not available because the drawing operation cannot be applied to the current selection."

The same thing happens if I try to access MyShape.Top after collapsing the selection.  What is weird is that if I try to access MyShape.Width or MyShape.Height after collapsing the selection, it works fine.  Any insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Your code works as expected for me, on Word 2010.

Comment: seems fine in 2013 too.